# Earning from news website is halal or haram?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, muslim-practices, internet

I am a blogger and earning from [Google adsense](https://www.google.com/adsense). I am going to start a news blog, but before starting I want to know whether sharing news like political news, sports news, weather news, hacking news, tech news and other local news is halal or haram? I will also share images in these news and video if needed.

Examples: [Propakistani.pk](https://propakistani.pk/), [apakistani.pk](http://apakistani.pk).

PS: I checked all the other questions related to websites but there is no satisfying answers.

Comment: I don't see any reason of it being haram, except if you spread any wrong news or non-islamic content or try to attract people with false advertisement, basically anything wrong in any other business should not be in it. Otherwise, i don't see anything wrong in it. Wallahu aa'lam

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal thanks for the info did you checked the websites i mentioned my website will be like that? JazakALLAH!